# AI CS6 not picking actual font size from svg text element

Tags: svg

I have an SVG file with a text element in it. I have set the font size property for the text element to "30px" but when i open the same file in AI CS6 it shows font size of "26.56px".

Following is the SVG file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="12in" height="12in" style="background-color: rgb(18, 52, 86)" viewBox="0 0 973 973" xml:space="preserve">
  <desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.4.0</desc>
  <defs></defs>
  <g transform="translate(396 279)">
    <text font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="30" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: #000000; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-124.5 29)">
      <tspan x="0" y="-15" fill="#000000">sdfsdfsdfdsfsdfdsfsd</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `30` equals `30px` and not `30pt`? **Edit**: [*For SVG, if a <length> is provided without a unit identifier (e.g., an unqualified number such as 128), the browser processes the <length> as a height value in the current user coordinate system.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/font-size)

Comment: I think by default there is px. Also when i opened the file in inkscape on linux it showed "33.45px". The font size is varying all the way through different environments

Comment: ..which makes sense if it tries to calculate the height of the font to fit 30 px (fonts on different OS'es have different sizes).

Comment: if we open the same file on same system in GIMP then too there is difference in font size. How can i set the svg font size property so that the same should appear on AI CS6

Comment: Have you tried adding `px` yourself?

Comment: Yes tried but the same result